# can we update case status from new to Work in progress when case is assigned from queue to any case owner

Tags: workflow, process-builder, visual-workflow

Is it possible through Workflow or process builder for case status from new to Work in progress when case is assigned from queue to any case owner.

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In workflow rules, if you use a formula for the rule criteria, you will see two possible values for owner : owner(queue) and owner(user)

So to evaluate transfer from queue to user, you can evaluate if priorvalue of owner(queue) is not blank && current value of owner(user) is not blank.

That should do the trick.  You probably have the same options in process builder but I have not tested.

[image: case fields]